# Pandas column of list: How to set the dtype of items

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe which has multiple columns containing lists and the length of the lists in each row are different:

```
tweetid tweet_date    user_mentions       hashtags
00112   11-02-2014    []                  []
00113   11-02-2014    [00113]             [obama, trump]
00114   30-07-2015    [00114, 00115]      [hillary, trump, sanders]
00115   30-07-2015    []                  []
```

The dataframe is a concat of three different dataframes and I'm not sure whether the items in the lists are of the same dtype. For example, in the user_mentions column, sometime the data is like:

```
[00114, 00115]
```

But sometimes is like this:

```
['00114','00115']
```

How can I set the dtype for the items in the lists?

Comment: Have you tried `pd.to_numeric(df['user_mentions'])`? That should convert the series to a numeric type.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Pandas DataFrames are not really designed to house lists as row/column values, so this is why you are facing difficulty. you could do

python3.x:

```
df['user_mentions'].apply(lambda x: list(map(int, x)))
```

python2.x:

```
df['user_mentions'].apply(lambda x: map(int, x))
```

In python3 when mapping a map object is returned so you have to convert to list, in python2 this does not happen so you don't explicitly call it a list.

In the above lambda, x is your row `list` and you are mapping the values to `int`.

Comment: Thanks. One more question: Is dtype of ['https://cnn.com'] different from [https://cnn.com] (first one has string quotes)? If yes, how to make their dtype the same?

Comment: @msmazh I believe they should both be treated as strings, but if you want to ensure that then just use the above and change `int` to `str` on your column of interest.

Answer (score 2):

`df['user_mentions'].map(lambda x: ['00' + str(y) if isinstance(y,int) else y for y in x])`

If your objective is to convert all `user_mentions` to `str` the above might help. I would also look into this post for [unnesting](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53218931/how-do-i-unnest-explode-a-column-in-a-pandas-dataframe). 
As mentioned ; pandas not really designed to house lists as values.

Answer (score 1):

this should work, where I'm making the first columns lists contain strings

```
df[0].apply((lambda x: [str(y) for y in x]))
```